# Everytime I clicked back when at my admin page it says "Document Expired"

Tags: php, codeigniter

The Problem is when I logged-in in my admin and go to other view forms from my admin and click back or go back the browser will display an error. and it says "Document Expired".

This is the Controller:

```
public function validate()  
  {  
       $this->load->library('form_validation');  
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Username', 'required');  
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required');  
       if($this->form_validation->run())  
       {  

            //true  
            $username = $this->input->post('user');  
            $password = $this->input->post('pass');  

            //model function  
            $this->load->model('add_mod');  

            $query = $this->add_mod->can_login($username, $password);

            $session_data = array(  

                'id' => $query['id'],
                'user' => $query['user']

             );  


             $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);  

            if($query)  

            {  


                $data['title'] = "Welcome ". $query['user'];

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('admin/home', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

            }  

            else  
            {  
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');  
                 redirect(base_url() . 'admin/login');  
            }  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            //false  
            $this->login();  
       }  
  }
```

This is the model

```
        public function can_login($username, $password)  
          {  
               $this->db->where('user', $username);  
               $this->db->where('pass', $password);  
               $query = $this->db->get('accounts');  

               if($query->num_rows() > 0)
               {  
                    return $query->row_array();
               }  
               else  
               {  
                    return false;       
               }  
          }
```

That's mostly my problem and stackoverflow won't let me post this because its mostly code here thanks in advance. More power from Philippines

Comment: I thing you are using POST method. Try with GET method.

Comment: Uhmm I tried it but still getting the same result, but thank you tho

Comment: Check my answer and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, add this at the start of the PHP code:

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cache_limiter','public');
session_cache_limiter(false);
?>
```

Or set Cache-Control header in your main page.

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age=900');
?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote the answer. Have a great day.